# How to run javascript code in JavaFx.WebView after the page is loaded?

Tags: java, javascript, javafx

i used this code

```
public WebMap() {
    webView = new WebView();
    final WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
    String url = getClass().getResource("map.html").toExternalForm();
    webEngine.load(url);

    final Deferred d = new Deferred();
    webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
        new ChangeListener<State>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue ov, State oldState, State newState) {
                if (newState == State.SUCCEEDED) {
                    d.resolve(webEngine);
                }
            }
        }
    );
    readyWebEngine = d.promise();
}
```

I don't call webEngine.executeScript directly but i use

```
readyWebEngine.then(new PromiseFunc() {
            @Override
    public Promise apply(Object oWebEngine) {
        WebEngine webEngine = (WebEngine)oWebEngine;
        webEngine.executeScript(script); // <=============================
                // return value doesn't matter
        return (new Deferred()).promise();
    }
});
```

So that the `script` string isn't evaluated until the promise is resolved (fulfilled) by the call to `d.resolve()`

Let's assume that the promise library is correct

The code works well for me, but a colleague of mine gets this error which is frustrating

```
netscape.javascript.JSException: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: gotoLatLng
[com.sun.webpane.platform.WebPage.twkExecuteScript(Native Method), com.sun.webpane.platform.WebPage.executeScript(WebPage.java:1438), javafx.scene.web.WebEngine.executeScript(WebEngine.java:811), packagename.WebMap.WebMap$1.apply(WebMap.java:36), packagename.WebMap.promise.Deferred$1$1.apply(Deferred.java:23), packagename.WebMap.promise.Deferred.resolve(Deferred.java:40), packagename.WebMap.WebMap$2.changed(WebMap.java:57), packagename.WebMap.WebMap$2.changed(WebMap.java:52), com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:196), com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:100), javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper$ReadOnlyPropertyImpl.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:195), javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:161), javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:130), javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:163), javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$LoadWorker.updateState(WebEngine.java:975), javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$LoadWorker.dispatchLoadEvent(WebEngine.java:1086), javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$LoadWorker.access$600(WebEngine.java:968), javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$PageLoadListener.dispatchLoadEvent(WebEngine.java:955), com.sun.webpane.platform.WebPage.fireLoadEvent(WebPage.java:2356), com.sun.webpane.platform.WebPage.fwkFireLoadEvent(WebPage.java:2204), com.sun.webpane.webkit.network.URLLoader.twkDidFinishLoading(Native Method), com.sun.webpane.webkit.network.URLLoader.access$1300(URLLoader.java:44), com.sun.webpane.webkit.network.URLLoader$6.run(URLLoader.java:691), com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:76), com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method), com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:17), com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(WinApplication.java:67), java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)]
```

The html page containing the javascript code is well tested. Let's assume there is no javascript errors there

The error `netscape.javascript.JSException: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: gotoLatLng` doesn't occure to me because javascript code is executed after the loadWorker's newState == State.SUCCEEDED.

The probleme is that in the stack trace of my coworker's program , we can see that the `WebEngine.executeScript(WebEngine.java:811)` was called by

```
packagename.WebMap.promise.Deferred.resolve(Deferred.java:40), packagename.WebMap.WebMap$2.changed(WebMap.java:57), packagename.WebMap.WebMap$2.changed(WebMap.java:52), com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:196), com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:100),
```

So, executeScript is called by the listener of the `load changed event` when `newState == State.SUCCEEDED` which means that the page is completely loaded and javascript inside s is loaded (variables should be defined).

Sorry because i don't have access to my coworker's code, but it's based on mine. Now i am not sure whether this code executes javascript code at the right moment

```
webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
        new ChangeListener<State>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue ov, State oldState, State newState) {
                if (newState == State.SUCCEEDED) {
                    webEngine.executeScript(script);
                }
            }
        }
    );
```

Any help?

Comment: Have you tried adding a listener to the `WebEngine`'s `documentProperty` instead of to the `loadWorker`'s `stateProperty`? I have some vague recollection that the load worker updates the state when the document is loaded but not necessarily parsed.

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
$(function(){
    alert("command:ready");
});
```

And then

```
engine.onAlert = new EventHandler<WebEvent<String>>() {
    @Override
    void handle(WebEvent<String> event) {
        if("command:ready".equals(event.getData())){
        //TODO: initialize
        }
    }
}
```

(seen here http://habrahabr.ru/company/codeorchestra/blog/198776/)

Comment: Thanks, instead of `.getLoadWorker().stateProperty()...`, I am using this now:

    `webEngine.setOnAlert(new EventHandler<WebEvent<String>>() {
      public void handle(WebEvent<String> event) {
       if ("variables:ready".equals(event.getData())) {
         System.out.println("document loaded");
         self.webEngineIsReady = true;
         d.resolve(webEngine);
     }}});`

and to avoid using jQuery, this javascript

`/* after initializing variables */
setTimeout(function () { alert("variables:ready"); }, 0);`

I will send this to my college. Hopefully, this will work.